# Wildcard for JSON Xpath in Node names

Tags: json, xpath

I'm looking for something like a contains XPath filter for JSON.

Here is the json I'm trying to filter (simplified example):

```
{
  "error":"error 123",
  "Sub":{
    "Sub2":{
      "Errors":[
        "a",
        "b",
        "c"
      ]
    },
    "errorList":[
      "xxx",
      "yyy"
    ]
  }
}
```

I'd like to get all the nodes that contain **error** as part of the node name (ignoring the case) -> this would be 'error', 'errorList' and 'Errors' here.

Using "$..['error']" will return just the node with name "error" (lowercase). I tried wildcards with no effect. It seems there isn't a contains() for json xpath...?

Comment: Are you using [JSONPath](https://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/)?

Comment: the newtonsoft version -> https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryJsonSelectToken.htm

Answer (score 1):

Using union operator and declaring element names is probably your best option. AFAIK, `JSONPath`can't apply regex filter expression (`?(@...=~)`) on element name. Depending the implementation of `JSONPath`, this should return 3 nodes :

```
   $..*['error','Errors','errorList']
```

Output :

```
[
   "error 123",
   [
      "xxx",
      "yyy"
   ],
   [
      "a",
      "b",
      "c"
   ]
]
```